# User Authentication/Login using OAuth

Tags: security, web-applications, authentication, oauth

I feel like this might be answered in another OAuth question here, but I couldn't find it...

I have implemented an OAuth provider on a web service I'm writing. OAuth consumers of my provider ("applications") have consumer keys, and get user access tokens in the typical OAuth way (get a request token, redirect to my producer to have the user authorize, get an access token, store that, etc). This all works fine.

My question is about how these OAuth consumers can authenticate someone on visiting them using *my* application's login credentials. Basically, when someone visits a consumer application, I would like:

1. User clicks login on consumer site.
2. User is redirected to my application and presented a login form.
3. After login, my application (OAuth provider), realizes that this user has already authorized this consumer, and redirects them back to the consumer.
4. Consumer is somehow told this user's username (or access token) in this request.

This is similar to the typical OAuth flow, except that the OAuth consumer does not need to exchange an authorized request token for an access token. Instead, as soon as the user has authenticated, the consumer now knows which user was authenticated, and can immediately begin making requests using their already-stored stored token/secret.

What are some security conditions I need to take into account when implementing this? Is this even possible to implement securely? Naïvely, this could be implemented by having the producer return some GET parameter to the consumer callback, with the user's username (or something else unique). However, an attacker could exploit this by making requests to the consumer's callback with the username of the user they want to attack.

Thoughts? Is this a solved problem that I'm trying to re-invent and re-implement? My platform is Java, if there are libraries that already do all of this.
Thank you!

Comment: It actually sounds like you want to implement an authentication **provider** service. Is this correct? So all you want it to return is something to the effect of "yeah, this user is kosher"?

Comment: Yep, that's basically what I want to do--have the consumers redirect to my website to have the user's enter their details, and then tell the consumer that they are good (and their username or something). I feel like this is more of an SSO problem, than one which should be solved with OAuth, probably?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is (3):

> "After login, my application (OAuth provider), realizes that this user
> has already authorized this consumer, and redirects them back to the
> consumer."

your OAuth-provider cannot realize that this user has already authenticated/authorized, because authorization was not done by your app. **Your app** should decide who is authenticated and who not, and what he is authorized for. This is the whole idea of OAuth.

If you want to implement an OAuth provider, that "knows" who is authenticated by the consumer, then the consumer has to send something to your provider, and it creates coupling between the consumer (OAuth client) and your app (OAuth provider).

The [OAuth SPEC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) defines exactly the generic interface of OAuth, so if you want to stick to it, you should avoid sending extra data to the provider, so it will not be coupled to a specific client.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm a little confused about why my OAuth provider cannot know if a user has previously authorized an OAuth consumer. After a consumer gets a permanent access token for a user, the access token is stored in the provider's database. When a user is authorizing a request token, my provider could query the access token table, and check if there is already an access token for this consumer-key/username pair. Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: " the access token is stored in the provider's database" - totally not recommended; read about it a bit; it opens many threats - if you save the tokens in a DB, it can be stolen, etc...